# Live streaming does not working when try to play live streaming videos using vitamio library

Tags: android, live-streaming, vitamio

Here is my Class

```
public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity implements OnInfoListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener {

    boolean isStart;
    VideoView mVideoView;
    ProgressBar pb;
    TextView downloadRateView, loadRateView;
    String videourl = "";
    ImageView img_add;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
            return;

        setContentView(R.layout.video_view);

        img_add = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_add);

        //  imageLoader.init(GetOption.getConfig(this));
        WebAPIHelper web = new WebAPIHelper(Constant.videoaddimage, VideoViewActivity.this, true);
        web.callRequestGet("http://fillatv.com/fillatv/service/get_banners.php");

        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.probar);

        downloadRateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.download_rate);
        loadRateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.load_rate);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

        mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                return false;
            }
        });

        Button btn_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

        btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                VideoViewActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        videourl = ((DataContainer) intent.getSerializableExtra("v_url")).link;
        //videourl = intent.getStringExtra("v_url");

        PlayVideo();

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void PlayVideo() {

        Log.e("video url", videourl);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videourl);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mVideoView.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                // optional need Vitamio 4.0
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
            }
        });

        mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no Streaming Found try after some time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        switch (what) {
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START:
                if (mVideoView.isPlaying()) {
                    mVideoView.pause();
                    isStart = true;
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    downloadRateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    loadRateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END:
                if (isStart) {
                    mVideoView.start();
                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    downloadRateView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    loadRateView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_DOWNLOAD_RATE_CHANGED:
                downloadRateView.setText("  " + extra + "kb/s" + "  ");
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        loadRateView.setText(percent + "%");
    }

    public void viewdata(String data) {
        String img;
        try {
            JSONArray j_array = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < j_array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject j_obj = j_array.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.print(j_obj.getString("status"));
                System.out.print(j_obj.getString("id"));
                System.out.print(j_obj.getString("Image"));
                img = j_obj.getString("Image");

                imageLoader.displayImage(img, img_add, GetOption.getOption());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

When Try to run it shows below error. spent one day to resolve this but can't find important hope you guys have solution for this.

```
E/Vitamio[4.2.6][Player]: FIND_NAME_SYM vvo, render_yuv
11-26 18:59:29.556 28707-28882/com.fillatv.live E/Vitamio[4.2.6][Player]: avformat_open_input: Invalid data found when processing input : -1094995529
11-26 18:59:29.556 28707-28879/com.fillatv.live E/Vitamio[4.2.6][Player]: error (1, -1094995529)
11-26 18:59:29.637 28707-28707/com.fillatv.live E/Vitamio[Player]: Error (1, -1094995529)
```

If anyone needs more detail please tell me,I will provide.Any help would be appreciated,Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get any solution for this

Comment: try this,[http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/stream-rtmp-live-android/]  . this might be helpful.

Comment: Google Play Store Rejected My Application For using Vitamio 4.x version. And its 5.x verions are not stable